# matplotlib.widgets.TextBox: change color

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, widget

Is there a way to change `TextBox` text color at any moment? I tried Google already; my question looks too trivial, but I am still at a loss.

`TextBox` methods:

```
: dir(matplotlib.widgets.TextBox)
Out[63]: 
[
 ...
 'active',
 'begin_typing',
 'connect_event',
 'disconnect',
 'disconnect_events',
 'drawon',
 'eventson',
 'get_active',
 'ignore',
 'on_submit',
 'on_text_change',
 'position_cursor',
 'set_active',
 'set_val',
 'stop_typing']
```

`AxesWidget` superclass methods:

```
: dir(matplotlib.widgets.AxesWidget)
Out[64]: 
[
 ...
 'active',
 'connect_event',
 'disconnect_events',
 'drawon',
 'eventson',
 'get_active',
 'ignore',
 'set_active']
```

Nothing suggestive. At least, to my eye.

Comment: have a look here : https://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html, using `color='yourcolor'`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer only - without knowing the fuller application it isn't obvious whether this helps you.  There are 2 pieces of text that you can change the color of: the label and the edit box.  Below shows how to change each, once.

```
import matplotlib.widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
tb = matplotlib.widgets.TextBox(ax, "Name:", initial="Jane Doe")
tb.label.set_color('red')      # label color
tb.text_disp.set_color('blue') # text inside the edit box
```

If you just want the label text to be different, that persists. But whenever the text inside the edit box (`text_disp`) is changed, it will be in black again. 
This is because widget recreates the text 
([by removing and then re-generating](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py#L797) and it will be in black again.

The [source for the text create method](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py#L723) does not have any arguments that the user could modify (color, font size/weight etc) or include as a TextBox instance attribute.

You could write your own subclass that overrides this method.  Or perhaps simply setting it after text has been entered is enough for you?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly my setting, and it works indeed.

Comment: At this time you no longer have to call `text_disp.set_color` again - it persists across changes in the box content